# How to make a bootstrap menubar with a submenu using jQuery UI?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3

I can make a menu with bootstrap and jQuery, but I have other code that conflicts with jquery UI.  Is there a way to make a dropdown menu just like these examples (basically a simple dropdown with submenus) but with jQuery UI?

http://www.bootply.com/nZaxpxfiXz#

http://www.bootply.com/7G8IVMj9k0#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plugins like [jQuery-Menu](https://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery-ipod-style-and-flyout-menus.html) that does this using jQuery UI. You can customize the [menu](https://jqueryui.com/menu/) widget to look like a dropdown:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#menu").menu();
  $('button').on('click', function() {
    $("#menu").toggleClass('hidden');
  });
});
```

```css
.ui-menu {
  width: 150px;
}
.hidden,
.ui-menu.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<button>Open</button>
<ul id="menu" class="hidden">
  <li class="ui-state-disabled">Aberdeen</li>
  <li>Ada</li>
  <li>Adamsville</li>
  <li>Addyston</li>
  <li>Delphi
    <ul>
      <li class="ui-state-disabled">Ada</li>
      <li>Saarland</li>
      <li>Salzburg an der schönen Donau</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Saarland</li>
  <li>Salzburg
    <ul>
      <li>Delphi
        <ul>
          <li>Ada</li>
          <li>Saarland</li>
          <li>Salzburg</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Delphi
        <ul>
          <li>Ada</li>
          <li>Saarland</li>
          <li>Salzburg</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Perch</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="ui-state-disabled">Amesville</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is there anyway to make the menu work like a bootstrap menu when you use it on your mobile device?

Comment: @SDJ there are many free jQuery plugins that does this http://adnantopal.github.io/slimmenu/# for example

Comment: Why is it necessary to use jQuery UI?! Anyway that's an example you mind find others using jQuery UI as well.

Comment: I hate to have to use JQuery UI, but we have pages and pages of old code that will be a royal pain to change for our mobile version of our site.  I am thinking that the hard way will have to do!